# Using "MS SQL Server Migration Tool for Access" to Migrate Data Only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using the "SQL Server Migration Tool for Access" to migrate a table from an Access database to SQL Server 2012. I used the migration wizard and a new table generated in the SQL Server with different data types and constraints from Access. But I changed and deleted some of the data types and constraints in SQL Server to meet the requirements of my web application.

Right now, I need to upgrade the SQL Server table with the newest data from Access. But when I use the migration wizard again, the data type and constraints in SQL Server are converted back to the original structure.

My question is: how can I migrate and upgrade the data to SQL Server without changing the current table structure? I mean only to add some rows to SQL Server, but not all those constraints. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you import data into SQL Server into a staging table 1st, and then do your upsert (Insert , Update) operations.

To import data into SQL Server you can use SQL Server's Import/Export Wizard

[image]

[image]

And just follow the simple instructions to import that data into a Temp Staging table.

Once you have your data in SQL Server then you can do the UPSERT operation doing as follows

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE Target_Table
     SET T.Column1 = S.Column1
        ,T.Column2 = S.Column2
        ,T.Column3 = S.Column3
    FROM Target_Table T INNER JOIN StaggingTable S
    ON T.PrimaryKey = S.PrimaryKey


    INSERT INTO Target_Table (Column1 , Column2, Column3)
    SELECT S.Column1 , S.Column2, S.Column3
    FROM StaggingTable S
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM Target_Table
                      WHERE PrimaryKey = S.PrimaryKey)

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```